# Any Linux containers with point-to-point host-guest network support?

Tags: networking, container

OpenVZ would be the only one I can name myself.

I've looked through some options of widely used "frameworks": Docker, rkt, LXC/LXD — all those are *bridge*-"centric" or at least based on *broadcast media* networking.

Instead I'm looking for convenient way of being able to assign any /32 IP-address to container and get proper bidirectional routing through "wormhole"/tunnel connecting guest and its host with minimal hacks or better w/o any.

Comment: https://thenewstack.io/container-networking-breakdown-explanation-analysis/

Comment: Seen that. It (ignorance's due) mentions point-to-point but absolutely in vain, saying: "it creates a virtual _ethernet_ pair"

Comment: OK, so the crux of your Q is: "containers seem to do P2P via a bridged i/f on the host, are there any that do it more natively?"

Comment: Roughly so. First of all some containers do it right (see OpenVZ). I'm looking for exactly same way of handling this (as I've explained in the question itself).

Comment: I'm familiar w/ OpenVZ, that what I used to use like ~10yrs ago to manage my infrastructure for the different "containers" of things I was managing.

Comment: So we can make Brotherhood of OpenVZ now!!!11

Comment: Veth pair can be used without a bridge. Assign IP addresses and you can communicate between container and host. When forwarding is enabled your containers can communicate outside/to other containers as well. Is your question about how to configure container networking without L2 bridging (I'm not familiar with OpenVZ networking)?

Comment: veth pair is how I did the networking in OpenVZ.

Comment: I've made chat; comment ping-pong is no option: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81322/room-for-poige-and-slm

Comment: @poige Was there ever a resolution to this in your chat?  I've been investigating this off & on for a few months and my conclusion so far is that it's not possible without writing the networking driver/setup scripts for oneself.

Comment: @PaulGear, it's hard to believe but the chat link still opens it.

Comment: So short answer is no. ;-(  I find it really sad that both KVM and Docker don't have built-in support for /32s & /128s on veth endpoints.  I'm still debating whether I should try to build it.

Comment: `veth` is an ethernet device, meaning it's broadcasting media in nutshell, meaning it has not p-t-p semantics by definition.